# Conceptual meaning of the Dickson construction

Tags: non-associative-algebras, quaternion-algebras

The Cayley-Dickson construction (a.k.a. Dickson construction or Dickson doubling) constructs a new *-algebra $A'$ out of a given *-algebra $A$. As a vector space $A' = A \oplus A$, and the multiplication and *-involution on $A'$ are customarily defined in a somewhat ad hoc manner ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction), [nlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cayley-Dickson+construction), [Baez "The octonions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105155) or also in the book of Schafer on Non-associative algebras).

**Is there a conceptual definition of $A'$ that does not involve any elementary fiddling around (e.g. in order to prove statements such as: $A'$ is associative iff $A$ is commutative and associative)?**